# AutoMapper SourceMember property of PropertyMap is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper, resolver

Automapper's TypeMap class provides memberwise mapping details. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to evaluate any lambda expressions, to get all PropertyMaps.

As a result, the mappings that are done via custom resolvers/ lambdas aren't available. Hence SourceMember property for every PropertyMap instance is null.

```
private string GetSourceName(PropertyMap propertyMap)
{
  var sourceName = propertyMap.SourceMember?.Name;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceName))
  {
      sourceName = propertyMap.CustomMapExpression?.Body.ToString();
  }

  return sourceName;
}
```

Here, sourceName is always empty.

Comment: Obviously, sometimes there is no source member. For example `MapFrom(_=>1)`. So that's expected.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Is there a way to get sourceProperty -> destinationProperty info with this limitation?

Comment: If `SourceMember` does what you need, use it, otherwise look elsewhere.